# How to validate a field in jsf

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-1.2

I have many fields in my `addNew.xhtml` page.
I have to do validations of the fields on client side. 
One of the field is `city`.

I want to get a validation error if I don't enter `city` which says `city cannot be left blank`.

Previously I was working on grails framework and it was a very easy task to customize validations.
Now I am working on jsf and I'm having trouble finding good examples on the internet to solve this issue.

Can you please help me out in implementing this validation

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/global.css" />

   </head>
       <body>
<div class="windowContents">
    <a4j:form style="width: 700px; height: 500px" ajaxSubmit="true"
        id="addNewRecord">

            <a4j:repeat value="#{addAction.editedtable}"
                var="address">

                <br />
                <br />

                    <table border="0" style="font-size: 12px; width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputText value="File ID:" /></td>
                            <td><h:outputText value="#{address.fileId}" /></td>

                            <td><h:outputText value="Insured Name" />:</td>
                            <td><h:outputText value="#{dataEntryAction.insuredName}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputText value="House No" /><span class="red">*</span>:</td>
                            <td><h:inputText value="#{address.houseNumber}" /></td>

                            <td><h:outputText value="Street" /><span class="red">*</span>:</td>
                            <td><h:inputText value="#{address.street}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputText value="City" />:</td>
                            <td><h:inputText id ="city" value="#{address.city}" required="false" requiredMessage="City is required" /></td>
                                            <h:message for="city" />


                        </tr>

                    </table>
            </a4j:repeat>
            <br />
            <h:panelGroup rendered="true">
                <a4j:commandButton value="save" image="../images/buttons/save.gif"
                      render="@form"
                    action="#{addAction.saveEditedAndPrepareHistory(addAction.userComment,user, addAction.editedtable)}"
                    reRender="dataEnrtyTable,dataEntryDetails"
                    oncomplete="javascript:Richfaces.hideModalPanel('addNewRecordPanel')"
                    style="align:center;" />

            </h:panelGroup>


    </a4j:form>
</div>
```

Comment: The basics about JSF validators are covered in [Mkyong JSF 2 tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/) (check the Converters & Validation section) and/or any other JSF 2 tutorial. Please refer there to learn this topic and come back when you have a real question.

Answer (score 3):

There are different options in JSF for achieving your task,

`1.` Client side validations.

You asked in your question regarding client side validation.

```
<tr>
   <td><h:outputText value="City" />:</td>
    <td><h:inputText value="#{address.city}" id="cityID"/></td>
</tr>

<h:commandLink action="#{yourBean.submitMethod}" onclick="checkCity(cityID)"> 
    <h:outputText value="Submit"></h:outputText>
</h:commandLink>

function checkCity(cityID)
{
    var cityEntered = $("#" + cityID).val();
    //Do whatever validations you want
}
```

**Not related to your question**
There are other ways also (which you have not asked in your question).

`2.` `maxlength` - The maximum number of characters that may be entered in this field.

```
<h:inputText id="cityID" value="#{yourBean.cityID}" maxlength="10"/>
```

`3`. Server side validations

Lets say you have not put `onclick` event for `h:commandLink` in point. 1

In your Facelets page,

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" layout="table" />


public String submitMethod() {
 try
 {
    FacesContext facesContext = null;
    facesContext=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    ArrayList <String> errorList= new ArrayList <String>();
    if(this.cityID.equals(//something))
     {
       errorList.add("//some message");
     }
     if(errorList != null && errorList.size() > 0)
     {
        for(int i=0;i<errorList.size();i++)
         {
           msg= (String)errorList.get(i);
           FacesMessage facemsg= new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,msg ,msg);
           facesContext.addMessage(null, facemsg);
         }
     }
 }
 catch(Exception e)
  {
    //Do error handling
  }

}
```

`4.` Built in validator components

```
<h:inputText id="cityID" value="#{yourBean.cityID}">
    <f:validateLength minimum="6" maximum="15"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: Thanx for answering . but i'm wondering that In function checkCity() you added a comment "  //Do whatever validations you want".Then what i have to write there to perform validation for empty field . Please answer if you know. :)

Comment: I meant to say that now you have the value of city entered present in `cityEntered ` variable. Using that, you can check if that suits your requirement like `if(cityEntered == "")` or some other complex checks.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly answering your question, in JSF 1.2+, this should do it:

```
<h:outputLabel for="city" value="City" />
<h:inputText id="city" value="#{address.city}" required="true" requiredMessage="City cannot be left blank." />
<h:message for="city" />
```

I think that these articles may be interesting to you:

- [Validator for multiple fields](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html)
- [JSF conversion and validation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf3/)

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanx but i'm using jsf version 1.2 so its not working out :(

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. This is for JSF 2.1. Is it an ongoing project? Can't you upgrade? There are lot's of improvements that could be handy. :) 
Best regards.

Comment: Sorry , i cannot upgrade because its client requirement and if we upgrade then a lot of regression is needed. So i'vl have to take  care of this version 1.2 only .

Comment: Ah, fine then. Well, I've updated my answer. Maybe you find it helpful. JSF has a predefined model for doing validation. Refrain from the temptation of using JavaScript hacks. Happy coding :)

Comment: i'm still struggling with the code . Its very important to complete this task today . So do u have any code for this or any good references?

Comment: @BalusC :thanx for suggestion but i tried required="true" requiredMessage="City is required" in my inputText but its not working  when i click on save button of my xhtml page

Comment: You're not rerendering those messages on ajax submit.