# How to render a new page in a javascript script

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, xhtml

I am using XHTML, JSF and JavaScript to create a form, validate that information has been submitted into selected fields onclick in a h:commandButton, and if validated, redirect to a different page homepage.xhtml. Everything works up to the redirection, which I can't get to work.

In the JavaScript function Validation(), I have tried location="homepage.xhtml", window.location.href="homepage.xhtml", location.url="homepage.xhtml" and a few others, but nothing seems to work. I have a feeling I'm supposed to have some sort of  statement which adds href="homepage.xhtml" to the h:commandButton if Validate() returns true, but I am unsure as to how to do that.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have added the relevant code below.

Button:

```
    <h:commandButton class="btn btn-warning" value="Continue" onclick="Validation()"/>
```

Validation

```
function Validation() {

    var nameCheck = document.getElementById('formdiv:cardName');
    var numCheck = document.getElementById('formdiv:cardNumber');
    var expCheck = document.getElementById('formdiv:expDate');

    console.log(nameCheck.value);
    console.log(numCheck.value);
    console.log(expCheck.value);

    var variablesToCheck = [nameCheck, numCheck, expCheck];

    for(i=0; i < variablesToCheck.length; i++){
        if(variablesToCheck[i].value == null || variablesToCheck[i].value == ""){

            alert("Fields marked with a * must be completed");
            return false;

        }
    }
    // This is where the redirection needs to go, I think...
    return true;
}
```

EDIT: Just noticed the if else statement is incorrect logically, but syntactically it shouldn't make a difference. The else part needs to be a statement outside of the loop without a condition; this code simply tries to redirect when the field it is checking has something in, not when all fields have something in.

EDIT 2: Loop corrected

Comment: Shouldn't you redirect after your for loop?

Comment: @JasperdeVries yeah I noticed that myself. Amended it now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515946/how-to-validate-a-field-in-jsf

Comment: Why don't you just use JSF `required="true"` on the inputs? See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4013410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need `h:commandButton` anyway you are using simple `javascript` validation
`h:commandButton` is rendered as `<input type="submit" ../>` its mission is 
to submit the form so what ever javascript you are writing your form will be submitted and your page is gonna be refreshed, So If you need it this way you have to force it not to submit the form,

However from understanding your needs all you need is simple `<a />` or `<button />` , Or you can just add `type="button"` into your `h:commandButton` ex:`<h:commandButton type="button" .../>`

Comment: I added type="button" and it worked just fine! Thanks for your help

Comment: @CGurrell: See the comment by BalusC above. Looks like you have a Porsche 911 but try to use it like a family car.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use.. 
    `window.location.replace('Your_url');` ..
or you can use..
    `window.location.href= 'Your_url';`  .. I guess there must be other functions too. If you want to open it in another window, like a popup, you can use..  `window.open('your_url');`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok so window.location.replace and window.location.href don't want to work, however window.open does work in the sense that it opens the page i want it to open in a new window. The problem is it keeps the page I want to close open.

Comment: Hmm. As the comment below says, why don't you try using a form with a submit? Sounds like a good idea to me!